# Pandas is not install in my 32 bit window operating system

Tags: python

When I tried to install pandas and matplotlib by using the command line $ pip install pandas and $pip install matplotlib , it doesn't work. Can any one tell me how can I install pandas and matplotliib in window 32 bit operating system?
Here is the result :

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.19.3
  WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages)
  WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\tesfasefineh34\appdata\local\programs\python\python310-32\lib\site-packages)
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f7/6c0dd488b5f5f1c0c1a48637df45046334d0be684faaf3536429f14aa9de/pandas-1.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=cbcb84d63867af3411fa063af3de64902665bb5b3d40b25b2059e40603594e87 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.7.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\tesfasefineh34\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\tesfasefineh34\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-1fabtbhw\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\tesfasefineh34\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bunrxlqc\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.18.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached pandas-1.3.1.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... /
```

Comment: Which version of Python? Which version of Pip?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the python pandas latest version or a specific version on windows either using pip command that comes with Python binary or conda if you are using Anaconda distribution. Before using either of these commands first you need to have Python or Anaconda distribution installed. If you already have either one installed then you can skip the first section of the document and directly jump to installing pandas. if not let’s see how to install pandas using these two approaches. You can use either one.
visit : https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/install-pandas-on-windows/